# count all record from a single query according to other query statement

Tags: php, mysql

So I want to count all the record from a query statement according to other query statement. In other words, I want to count all my `totalviewer`, from a same `page` from all the `userip`

i will put the code

```
<?php
  // gets the user IP Address and the page adress name link
  $user_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
  $pagenew = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];    
  $check_ip = "select userip from pageview where page='$pagenew' and userip='$user_ip'";
  $query1 = mysqli_query($db_conx_count, $check_ip);
  if (!$check_ip || mysqli_num_rows($query1)>=1)
  {

  }
  else
  {
     // adauga o query
    $insertview = "INSERT INTO pageview (id, page, userip) values ('','$pagenew','$user_ip')";
    $query2 = mysqli_query($db_conx_count, $insertview);
    // updateaza query cu un nou user
    $updateview = "UPDATE pageview SET totalviewer = totalviewer+1 where page='$pagenew'";
    $query3 = mysqli_query($db_conx_count, $updateview);

  }
?>


  <?php
    $stmt = "SELECT totalviewer FROM pageview WHERE page='$pagenew'";
    $query_stmt = mysqli_query($db_conx_count, $stmt);
  ?>

  <div class="vizualizari">Vizualizări <?php echo mysqli_num_rows($query_stmt);?></div>
    <?php mysqli_close($db_conx_count);?>
```

at the momemt in the db is more query from a userip and other from others userip at the same page

Comment: I'd change the db structure, Columns = `page, userip, views`. Make `page, userip` a unique constraint, give `views` a default value of `0`. Then `INSERT INTO pageview ... on duplicate update set views = views + 1`. I'd also convert the IP to an integer.

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. Maybe you want `SELECT SUM(totalviewer)`?